# Can we make piecewise PDFs or CDFs into a single CDF?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory

> Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables, both uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$. That is, $$f_{X}(a)=f_{Y}(a) =  \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $0 < a <
>  1$} 
> \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>   Let $P(X+Y \le a) =  F_{X+Y}(a)\ $. Find  $\Large \frac{\mathrm{d}a}{a} \normalsize \left( F_{X+Y}(a)\right)= f_{X+Y}(a)$.

Here is how I solved this problem: All possible values of $(X, Y)$ are contained within the square region having vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$. To see what $x + y \le a$ means more clearly, we can imagine lines $x + y = a$ for different values of $a$ which cross through or run tangent to the square.

I found the probability distribution function $P(X + Y \le a)$ as follows

$$\begin{align}
&P(X+Y \le a ,\ 0 \le a \le 1 ) = \int_0^a \int_0^{a-y} f_X(x) f_X(y)\ dx\ dy = \frac{a^2}{2} \\ 
&P(X+Y \le a ,\  1 \lt a \lt 2) = \int_0^1 \int_{1-y}^{a-y} f_X(x) f_X(y)\ dx\ dy - \int_0^{a-1} \int_{1}^{a-y} f_X(x) f_X(y)\ dx\ dy  \\
&P(X+Y \le a ,\  1 \lt a \lt 2 ) = a-1 
\end{align}$$

So it appears we have a probability distribution function, $P(X+Y \le a) = F_{X+Y}(a)$, that has two cases ($0 \le a \le 1,\ \  1 \lt a \lt 2$), as if it's a piecewise function.

Can this function $F_{X+Y}(a) = P(X+Y \le a)$ be rewritten a single, non-piecewise function? Is there a straightforward or clever way to do so? Or, is there a reason why it should not or cannot?

Comment: you can write any piece-wise function as a single function using unit-step ( heaviside step functions ) and if an impulse is there you can use the dirac-delta function .

Comment: You may wish to recalculate the cdf on the part $1\lt a\lt 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas um, how? $a \lt 1$ *and* $a \gt 1$? Is that possible?

Comment: OOps, typo. I meant $1$ to $2$. Your formula for the cdf of the sum is I think not correct on that part. I believe it should be something like $1-\frac{(2-a)^2}{2}$ there. Something like that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional probability distributions are continuous. You can construct one by conditioning on $\{a < 1\}$ or $\{ 1 < a < 2 \}$